# How to get resource id of terraform resource inside of a for_each loop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to create azure firewall network rules using terraform.

There are quite a few source ips I have to use in my rules collection, so I created an ip group ("ipg_onpremise"). Now I need to reference the ip group from my rule collection. Unfortunately I can not use the name ("ipg_onpremise") for that, but the resource id ("/subscriptions/xx-xx-xx/resourceGroups/rg-shared/providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/ipg_onpremise").

This is my code:

```
# firewall.tf

resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub" {
  name                = "onprem-hub"
  azure_firewall_name = azurerm_firewall.fw_shared.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.name
  priority            = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rule_priority
  action              = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rule_action

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rules
    content {
        name                  = rule.value.name
        description           = lookup(rule.value, "description", null)
        source_addresses      = lookup(rule.value, "source_addresses", null)
        source_ip_groups      = lookup(rule.value, "source_ip_groups" , null)
        destination_addresses = lookup(rule.value, "destination_addresses", null)
        destination_ip_groups = lookup(rule.value, "destination_ip_groups", null)
        destination_ports     = lookup(rule.value, "destination_ports", null)
        protocols             = lookup(rule.value, "protocols", null)
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_ip_group" "ipg_onpremise" {
  name                = "ipg-onpremise"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.name

  cidrs = var.ipg_onpremise_cidrs
}
```

```
# terraform.tfvars

nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rules = [
    {    
        name                  = "onprem->hub"
        source_addresses      = []
        destination_addresses = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
        destination_ports     = ["*"]
        protocols             = ["Any"]
        source_ip_groups      = ["ipg_onpremise"]
        destination_ip_groups = []
    },
]
```

When running terraform, I get the following error:

```
azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating/updating Network Rule Collection "onprem-hub" in Firewall "fw_shared" (Resource Group "rg-shared"): network.AzureFirewallsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="AzureIpGroupsInvalidResourceId" Message="The resourceId ipg_onpremise is an invalid resourceId of an IpGroup." Details=[]
│ 
│   with azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub,
│   on firewall.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub":
│   34: resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub" {
│
```

I have searched for an idea on how to get the id inline, but couldn't find any.
Can someone please give me a push into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The ID is part of `azurerm_ip_group`. So you have to refactor a lot of your code:

```
resource "azurerm_ip_group" "ipg_onpremise" {

  for_each            = {for idx, val in var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rules: idx => val}

  name                = each.value.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.name

  cidrs = var.ipg_onpremise_cidrs
}


resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub" {
  name                = "onprem-hub"
  azure_firewall_name = azurerm_firewall.fw_shared.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_shared.name
  priority            = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rule_priority
  action              = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rule_action

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.nrc_fw_shared_onprem_hub_rules
    content {
        name                  = rule.value.name
        description           = lookup(rule.value, "description", null)
        source_addresses      = lookup(rule.value, "source_addresses", null)
        source_ip_groups      = azurerm_ip_group.ipg_onpremise[rule.value.name].id 
        destination_addresses = lookup(rule.value, "destination_addresses", null)
        destination_ip_groups = lookup(rule.value, "destination_ip_groups", null)
        destination_ports     = lookup(rule.value, "destination_ports", null)
        protocols             = lookup(rule.value, "protocols", null)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, but that actually does not solve my problem. The azure provider only accepts the id of the ipgroup ("/subscriptions/xx-xx-xx/resourceGroups/rg-shared/providers/Microsoft.Network/ipGroups/ipg_onpremise"), not the name. I need a way to convert the name of the ip group into it's resource id.

Comment: @Timbo I updated the answer, but you have to pretty  much scrape your current code, and start from scratch writing new one.